# Can't see images in posts after migrating site to subdomain

Tags: images, migration

After moving my site to a a subdomain for testing, everything works fine except the images. I can see the images in metaslider plugin but all the other images on the site are blank. 
All images are visible in the media library and the image URLs on my posts are correct, but nothing is showing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a Search/Replace plugin (I like "Better Search and Replace") to look for any old URLs. (That plugin has a 'test-but-don't-change' option.) If you find any old URL, use the same plugin to replace with the new URL.

Although you can use SQL commands to make the changes, the plugin has always worked better and faster and easier for me.

I'd also check the URLs for the media item on the Media page. Might be that the old URL is in there. The plugin will fix that.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It turns out it was something wrong with the jetpack plugin. When I deactivate "lazy loading" feature from the plugin everything started working again.